# How to improve this custom MLA formatting?

Tags: header-footer, margins, templates, mla-style

I am required to follow a certain formatting that resembles MLA style. There has to be a 1/2" header top margin (the header being the "Essay #1:..." part). There has to be a 1" body top margin (the body started with "Name Surname"). And there have to be 1" margins from the left, right, and bottom. The header has to contain the assignment name and the word count. And the header in the body has to include name and surname, teacher's name, class and period, and the date. On subsequent pages only the right header should be included, and it has to be in the form of "Surname pagenum". There has to be a 1/2" margin from the top to the header, and there has to be a 1" margin from the top to the text (this causes the most problems). And of course 1" margins from the left, right, and bottom. And everything has to be double spaced.

I managed to somehow make my LaTeX document follow that formatting, but it's not nice. The `\vspace*{0.2in}` thing is especially nasty, but for some reason it works. I don't even know why 0.2in. I just experimented and this one seemed to work.

Now there are many things that could be improved. The obvious thing is the margins. I feel like there has to be a better way to do this, and I feel like my current way of achieving this is not very flexible nor reliable: it's going to break eventually (for example when I plan on using `biblatex`). Being able to set up the header information by using commands such as `\name{...}` and `\assignment{...}` and maybe being able to make the header using `\makeheader{}` would be a cool feature, but not necessary. However, having the formatting in a separate package to import (like the `mla` package), would be a feature that would be even better, but again not a necessity.

I'd already be happy if somebody could tell me how to make the headers nice and reliable.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[left=1in, right=1in, top=0.5in, bottom=1in, headheight=0in, headsep=0in]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\fancypagestyle{firststyle}
{
   \fancyhf{}
   \fancyhead[R]{\doublespacing Argumentative Essay \#1: Lorem Ipsum\\
WordCount:999}
}

\fancypagestyle{pagenum}
{
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[R]{\doublespacing Surname \thepage\\}
}

\pagestyle{pagenum}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

\setlength{\parindent}{0.5in}

\setmainfont {URW Bookman L}

\RaggedRight
\parindent=0.5in
\doublespacing
\thispagestyle{firststyle}
\begin{document}
\vspace*{0.2in}
\noindent Name Surname\\
\noindent Mr. Smith\\
\noindent AP Language - 7\textsuperscript{th} Pd.\\
\noindent 4 March 2015\\
\centerline{Lorem Ipsum}

\lipsum{}

\end{document}
```

Example output:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to set up things to make setting the document information easier, then a key-value interface might be a good way to go.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[
  showframe, % <-- to help visualize
  left=1in, right=1in, top=1in, bottom=1in,
  headheight=40pt, headsep=0in]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[grid,
      gridcolor=red!20,
      subgridcolor=green!20,
      %texcoord,
      gridunit=in]{eso-pic} % <-- to help visualize


\fancypagestyle{pagenum}
{
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[R]{\doublespacing Surname \thepage\\}
}

\pagestyle{pagenum}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\setlength{\parindent}{0.5in}
\setmainfont {URW Bookman L}

\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\keys_define:nn {mla}
{
  gname   .tl_set:N = \l_mla_gname_tl,  % given name(s)
  sname   .tl_set:N = \l_mla_sname_tl,  % surname
  course  .tl_set:N = \l_mla_course_tl,
  date    .tl_set:N = \l_mla_date_tl,
  title   .tl_set:N = \l_mla_title_tl,
  wc      .tl_set:N = \l_mla_wc_tl,
  gname   .initial:n = John {~} James,
  sname   .initial:n = Smith,
  course  .initial:n = ??,
  date    .initial:n = ??,
  title   .initial:n = ??,
  wc      .initial:n = ??,
}



\NewDocumentCommand{\titleinfo}{ m }
 {
  \keys_set:nn { mla } { #1 }
 }


\NewDocumentCommand{\printtitle} {O{-0.5in}}
{
  \vspace*{\dimexpr#1 - \baselineskip\relax}%
  \group_begin:
  \parskip 0pt
  \parindent 0pt
  Name {~} Surname  \hfill \l_mla_title_tl
  \newline
   \l_mla_gname_tl {~} \l_mla_sname_tl \hfill \l_mla_wc_tl
  \newline
  \l_mla_course_tl
  \newline
  \l_mla_date_tl
  \group_end:
}

\ExplSyntaxOff


\titleinfo{
% gname=, sname=, course=, title=,
wc=999, date=4 March 2015
}



\RaggedRight
\parindent=0.5in
\doublespacing
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\printtitle % <-- print the document data


\centerline{Lorem Ipsum}

\lipsum{}

\end{document}
```

In order to get different heights for the left and right side of the first page, you could use this code (note that I have used the `\RenewDocumentCommand` here):

```
\newlength\raiseright     
\setlength\raiseright{\dimexpr 1in - \baselineskip\relax}  

\RenewDocumentCommand{\printtitle} {}      
{%          
  \group_begin:
  \parskip 0pt  
  \parindent 0pt      
  \vspace*{-\raiseright}\hfill \l_mla_title_tl \par 
  \hfill \l_mla_wc_tl \par    
  \vspace*{-.5\baselineskip}%    
  Name {~} Surname     
  \newline     
  \l_mla_gname_tl {~} \l_mla_sname_tl     
  \newline    
  \l_mla_course_tl     
  \newline  
  \l_mla_date_tl  
  \group_end:  
}
```

Comment: This works quite nicely except that the left header is on the same height as the right header. However, the left header is supposed to have a 1" margin from the top, which complicates things a lot.

Comment: Oh, I thought it was supposed to be the same. (It was late.) That's easy to fix.

Comment: I added the code between the \titleinfo part and the \RaggedRight command. However xelatex says: http://pastebin.com/7qPqHvDN

Comment: You can't put that there: this is explicit `LaTeX3` code and must be included between `\ExplExyntaxOn` and `\ExplSyntaxOff`.

Answer (score 4):

For the messiness:

### ***Read the console output. Packages often try to tell you useful stuff.***

For example, `fancyhdr` is as close to knocking you over the head as a piece of software can come without evolving into a robot. It is desperately trying to get your attention:

```
Package Fancyhdr Warning: \headheight is too small (39.36879pt): 
 Make it at least 39.5248pt.
 We now make it that large for the rest of the document.
 This may cause the page layout to be inconsistent, however.
```

It tells you (1) things will be a mess (2) why they will be a mess and (3) how to avoid the mess. You have `headheight=0pt`. You need at least `headheight=40pt` with your current configuration.

The real problem here, though, is that `fancyhdr` is designed to create running headers and footers. Don't use it to create the document heading on the first page. Instead use `\maketitle` or the `titlepage` environment as applicable. The `titling` package may be helpful here.

So don't use `firststyle` at all. Just define `pagenum`. That will give you a more reasonable value for `headheight` on the console output. Use that value (rounded up) in the options you pass `geometry`. Then use `titling` (or similar) to deal with the title for the first page.

## EDIT

Here's a way of implementing the above suggestions. I may not have entirely understood your requirements but hopefully this is enough to get you started. Note that you can easily wrap the configuration into a package file or use `\input{}` to enter it as a standard preamble.

This uses `titling` although somewhat minimally. The first page headings and title are automatically generated at `\begin{document}`. The contents of the output is specified using a number of commands. Each takes a single, mandatory argument.

```
\firstnames{}% e.g. Edward Mickleston Henry Patrick
\surname{}% e.g. Barrow-Tottenhals
\instructor{}% e.g. Prof.\ Dumbledore
\assignmenttype{}% e.g. Communicative Doodles
\assignmentnumber{}% e.g. 3,948.567
\subject{}% e.g. English Literature, History of French Snails, The Totalitarian State (Classified)
```

The code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{calc,titling}
\usepackage[left=1in, right=1in, top=1in, bottom=1in, headheight=24pt, headsep=.5in-24pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\fancypagestyle{pagenum}{%
    \fancyhf{}%
    \fancyhead[R]{\doublespacing \mysurname{} \thepage}}
\pagestyle{pagenum}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

\setlength{\parindent}{0.5in}
\RaggedRight
\parindent=0.5in
\doublespacing

\setmainfont {URW Bookman L}

\newcommand*\myfirstnames{}
\newcommand*\mysurname{}
\newcommand*\myassignmenttype{Short Answers}% set a default
\newcommand*\myassignmentnumber{}
\newcommand*\myinstructor{}
\newcommand*\mysubject{}
\newcommand*\firstnames[1]{\renewcommand*\myfirstnames{#1}}
\newcommand*\surname[1]{\renewcommand*\mysurname{#1}}
\newcommand*\assignmenttype[1]{\renewcommand*\myassignmenttype{#1}}
\newcommand*\assignmentnumber[1]{\renewcommand*\myassignmentnumber{#1}}
\newcommand*\instructor[1]{\renewcommand*\myinstructor{#1}}
\newcommand*\subject[1]{\renewcommand*\mysubject{#1}}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \author{\myfirstnames{} \mysurname}%
  \newsavebox{\firstpageheader}%
  \sbox{\firstpageheader}{%
    \begin{minipage}[T]{\textwidth}%
      \RaggedLeft\normalfont\normalsize \myassignmenttype{} \#\myassignmentnumber: \thetitle\par\thedate\par\mbox{}
    \end{minipage}}%
  \newlength\firstpageheaderheight%
  \settototalheight{\firstpageheaderheight}{\usebox{\firstpageheader}}%
  \thispagestyle{empty}%
  \vspace*{-.5in}%
  \noindent\usebox{\firstpageheader}
  \noindent
  \begin{minipage}[T]{\textwidth}
    \RaggedRight
    \myfirstnames{} \mysurname{}\par
    \myinstructor\par
    \mysubject\par
    \thedate\par
    \centering\thetitle\par\mbox{}
  \end{minipage}}

\title{Lorem Ipsum}
\firstnames{Aardent Ivanovitch}
\surname{Eegleberg}
\date{4 March, 2015}
\assignmenttype{Argumentative Essay}
\assignmentnumber{1}
\instructor{Mr.\ Smith}
\subject{AP Language - 7\textsuperscript{th} Pd.}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```

The results are, of course, predictably ugly. This is, however, a function of the requirements and not my (or your) fault!

You should, however, offer your instructors copies of your homework typeset with a default layout (or with one of the KOMA classes) as an alternative....

[image: typographic horror]

Comment: While setting headheight to 40pt helps to get rid of the warning, the right header now gets cut off at top of the document: there is virtually no margin. Titling seems to work quite nicely, but using \renewcommand{\pagenum}{...} does not work, maybe I'm not even supposed to do that.

Comment: @CodeHero -- You are not. You have not defined a command called `\pagenum`; therefore, there is nothing to redefine.

Comment: I meant: just define `pagenum`. Don't define `firststyle` as well. And take the value of `headheight` from the console output when you do so - don't use the value of `40pt` you get when you do define `firststyle`. The point is not to use a header to style your first page at all.

Comment: @CodeHero See edit.

Comment: I really like the structure of the code, and it does everything like it should except that the left header has a 1.5in margin instead of a 1in margin.

I am fairly sure that my instructor won't take a paper with any other formatting, so offering one in a standard format will not work.

Comment: @CodeHero Well, no. It doesn't. It has what it is defined to have. But the problem may be that you are not using 'margin' in the same way as `geometry`. Right now the top of the headers correspond. Is it that you want the bottom of the headers to correspond? And what kind of course are you taking that your instructor doesn't have better things to do than measure your margins? [I have seen administrators take out a ruler and tell me something is 2mm off the required layout - never an instructor.]

Comment: Well, it's possible that I'm using margin or grid wrong, but this is how it looks like https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7ZZQBxCogNpYVl5RDNlQUYxS0U/view?usp=sharing

This is how the result of jon's suggested code looks like: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7ZZQBxCogNpWEVyellnYWxCdmM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @CodeHero The trouble is that it isn't clear to me, anyway, what you want it to look like. You can adjust the lengths as you wish, so if the margin is really meant to be something else, just change the value. Or use the code in the other answer if that worked better?